# .htaccess and blank values

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)/([0-9\.]+)/(.*)/(.*)$ m.pl?id=$1&cv=$2&cu=$3&qty=$4
```

So, a link like `cpa/11/axg/4` gets redirected correctly.

But if the 3rd value is blank, i.e.

`cpa/11//4`, it does not get redirected to the rule defined above.

I am not sure how to address this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the third parameter is optional, solved it as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)/([0-9\.]+)/?(.*)/(.*)$ m.pl?id=$1&cv=$2&cu=$3&qty=$4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 separate rules to address this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)/([0-9.]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ m.pl?id=$1&cv=$2&qty=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)/([0-9.]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ m.pl?id=$1&cv=$2&cu=$3&qty=$4 [L,QSA]
```